# SSH command to start "webdriver-manager" on slave machine using Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, ssh, protractor, jenkins-plugins

I am actually using protractor and Jenkins to run all the test on remote machine. I am starting "webdriver-manager" manually on remote machine and triggering Jenkins to  run the tests, is there a way i can start "webdriver-manager" using Jenkins? like on pre-build step using SSH or "maven" script
Your comment will really appreciated.﻿

Answer (score 1):

We've solved it using `grunt`, there is a specific [`grunt-protractor-webdriver` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-webdriver) that would start the webdriver-manager for you:

> This Grunt task starts a Selenium WebDriver, blocks until it's ready
>   to accept connections, and then leaves it running in the background
>   until the Grunt process finished.

There is also [`grunt-protractor-runner`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-runner).

Comment: thanks for the comment, this is helpful, but this is to run locally, we need to install "grunt-protractor-webdriver" plugin and also in config file we need to mention it right?
I would like to know if there is a command that can start "web-driver" in slave through Jenkins.

Comment: @Nick first write grunt/gulp task to run your e2e tests locally. Once the tests  (web server, webdriver etc) are executed through grunt/gulp locally, you will be able just issue the same grunt commands on the server via SSH..may be I'm missing something you are asking about, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about grunt. I have a configuration file and i run this file through command prompt locally, on the other cmd window i run "webdriver-manager" separately. so now i want to run this scripts on Jenkins. but in-order to run through Jenkins, on slave machine i need to start webdriver manager manually. Now i don't want to start webdriver manager manually on slave.
I don't run my scripts through grunt, i run my scripts using a config file. Can i include anything in my config file and start webdriver manager?